# Modularized Shiny: HTML style tags does not work for namespaced tooltip

Tags: html, shiny, hover, tooltip, modular

Hi thanks for any help in advance.

I am developping a Shiny app for EDA and want to add a hover tooltip to a ggplot scatterplot.

[This example](https://gitlab.com/snippets/16220) works fine until the axes are log transformed, since the tooltip coordinates are way out of range of the plot.

[Example 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38917101/how-do-i-show-the-y-value-on-tooltip-while-hover-in-ggplot2/38919892#38919892) in this answer works with log transformed scatterplot, but when I use it in a Shiny module, the `tags$style` and `tags$script` elements are not passed on to the tooltip UI object `my_tooltip` and the actual text in the tooltip. My suspicion is when `my_tooltip` is referenced in `tags$style`, the namespace is left out so `my_tooltip` never uses the HTML element.

I do not know enough HTML to edit Example 3. Below I provide three reproducible examples modified from the two sources quoted above which all do part of what I want to achieve. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

### Reproducible example 1: works with log scale but not in a Shiny module

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(

  selectInput("logX", "Log scale",
              choices=coordoptions,
              selected="identity"),
  selectInput("logY", "Log scale",
              choices=coordoptions,
              selected="identity"),

  tags$head(tags$style('
                       #my_tooltip {
                       position: absolute;
                       width: 300px;
                       z-index: 100;
                       padding: 0;
                       }
                       ')),

  tags$script('
              $(document).ready(function() {
              // id of the plot
              $("#distPlot").mousemove(function(e) { 

              // ID of uiOutput
              $("#my_tooltip").show();         
              $("#my_tooltip").css({             
              top: (e.pageY + 5) + "px",             
              left: (e.pageX + 5) + "px"         
              });     
              });     
              });
              '),

  selectInput("var_y", "Y-Axis", choices = names(iris)),
  plotOutput("distPlot", hover = "plot_hover", hoverDelay = 0),
  uiOutput("my_tooltip")

  )

server <- function(input, output) {

      output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    req(input$var_y)
    ggplot(iris, aes_string("Sepal.Width", input$var_y)) + 
      geom_point() +
      scale_x_continuous(trans=input$logX) + 
      scale_y_continuous(trans=input$logY) 
  })

  output$my_tooltip <- renderUI({
    hover <- input$plot_hover 
    y <- nearPoints(iris, input$plot_hover)[input$var_y]
    req(nrow(y) != 0)
    verbatimTextOutput("vals")
  })

  output$vals <- renderPrint({
    hover <- input$plot_hover 
    y <- nearPoints(iris, input$plot_hover)[input$var_y]
    req(nrow(y) != 0)
    y
  })  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

### Reproducible example 2: works without transformation but tooltip out of range with log transformations

```
library("shiny")
library("ggplot2")

ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Tooltips in ggplot2 + shiny"),

  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("logX", "Log scale",
                choices=coordoptions,
                selected="identity"),
    selectInput("logY", "Log scale",
                choices=coordoptions,
                selected="identity"),
    width = 3
  ),

  mainPanel(

    # this is an extra div used ONLY to create positioned ancestor for tooltip
    # we don't change its position
    div(
      style = "position:relative",
      plotOutput("scatterplot", 
                 hover = hoverOpts("plot_hover", delay = 100, delayType = "debounce")),
      uiOutput("hover_info")
    ),
    width = 7
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$scatterplot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = hp)) +
      geom_point() +
      scale_x_continuous(trans=input$logX) + 
      scale_y_continuous(trans=input$logY) 
  })


  output$hover_info <- renderUI({
    hover <- input$plot_hover
    point <- nearPoints(mtcars, hover, threshold = 5, maxpoints = 1, addDist = TRUE)
    if (nrow(point) == 0) return(NULL)

    # calculate point position INSIDE the image as percent of total dimensions
    # from left (horizontal) and from top (vertical)
    left_pct <- (hover$x - hover$domain$left) / (hover$domain$right - hover$domain$left)
    top_pct <- (hover$domain$top - hover$y) / (hover$domain$top - hover$domain$bottom)

    # calculate distance from left and bottom side of the picture in pixels
    left_px <- hover$range$left + left_pct * (hover$range$right - hover$range$left)
    top_px <- hover$range$top + top_pct * (hover$range$bottom - hover$range$top)

    # create style property fot tooltip
    # background color is set so tooltip is a bit transparent
    # z-index is set so we are sure are tooltip will be on top
    style <- paste0("position:absolute; z-index:100; background-color: rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.85); ",
                "left:", left_px + 2, "px; top:", top_px + 2, "px;")

    # actual tooltip created as wellPanel
    wellPanel(
      style = style,
      p(HTML(paste0("<b> Car: </b>", rownames(point), "<br/>",
                    "<b> mpg: </b>", point$mpg, "<br/>",
                    "<b> hp: </b>", point$hp, "<br/>",
                    "<b> Distance from left: </b>", left_px, "<b>, from top: </b>", top_px)))
    )
  })
}

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

### Reproducible example 3: works with log scales and in a module but `tags$style` does not work for `my_tooltip` (not floating over plot)

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

AUI<-function(id){

  ns<-NS(id)

  fluidPage(

    selectInput(ns("logX"), "Log scale",
                choices=coordoptions,
                selected="identity"),
    selectInput(ns("logY"), "Log scale",
                choices=coordoptions,
                selected="identity"),

    tags$head(tags$style('
                       #my_tooltip {
                       position: absolute;
                       width: 300px;
                       z-index: 100;
                       padding: 0;
                       }
                       ')),

    tags$script('
              $(document).ready(function() {
              // id of the plot
              $("#distPlot").mousemove(function(e) { 

              // ID of uiOutput
              $("#my_tooltip").show();         
              $("#my_tooltip").css({             
              top: (e.pageY + 5) + "px",             
              left: (e.pageX + 5) + "px"         
              });     
              });     
              });
              '),

    selectInput(ns("var_y"), "Y-Axis", choices = names(iris)),
    plotOutput(ns("distPlot"), hover = ns("plot_hover"), hoverDelay = 0),
    uiOutput(ns("my_tooltip"))

  )
}  


A <- function(input, output, session) {

  ns<-session$ns

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    req(input$var_y)
    ggplot(iris, aes_string("Sepal.Width", input$var_y)) + 
      geom_point() +
      scale_x_continuous(trans=input$logX) + 
      scale_y_continuous(trans=input$logY) 
  })

  output$my_tooltip <- renderUI({
    hover <- input$plot_hover 
    y <- nearPoints(iris, input$plot_hover)[input$var_y]
    req(nrow(y) != 0)
    verbatimTextOutput(ns("vals"))
  })

  output$vals <- renderPrint({
    hover <- input$plot_hover 
    y <- nearPoints(iris, input$plot_hover)[input$var_y]
    req(nrow(y) != 0)
    y
  })  
}

ui<-AUI("id")

server <- function(input, output, session){
      callModule(A, "id")
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48929528/whats-the-best-way-to-write-custom-javascript-for-r-shiny-module-that-uses-modu

Answer (score 1):

I didn´t manage to reproduce your example, but this should work:

```
tags$style(
    paste0("#",
        ns(my_tooltip),
        "{
          position: absolute;
          width: 300px;
          z-index: 100;
          padding: 0;
         }"
    )
)
```

So basically you´re letting the HTML code know what namespace your `ns` function has assigned

You can check a similar example in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52382721/10785201)

Comment: I needed "my_tooltip" in quotation marks, but apart from that, that was my solution :)